# Iterate through rows of list in R

Tags: r

I am working in R and I am wanting to iterate through the rows of a list and to reference the column value by name like this:

```
for(row in Data) {
    name <- row$name
    age <- row$age
    #do something cool here
}
```

Where my data looks like this:

```
name, age, gender, weight
Bill, 23, m, 134
Carl, 40, m, 178
```

I know that this should be trivial but I can not find help on it. Thanks ahead of time.

So here is the raw data I am working with. The earlier table was an example:

```
structure(list(startingTemp = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), 
    endingTemp = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), movesPerStep = c(200000L, 
    100000L, 20000L, 10000L, 2000L), coolingCoefficient = c(0.99, 
    0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99), numberTempSteps = c(459L, 459L, 
    459L, 459L, 459L), costPerRun = c(91800000L, 45900000L, 9180000L, 
    4590000L, 918000L)), .Names = c("startingTemp", "endingTemp", 
"movesPerStep", "coolingCoefficient", "numberTempSteps", "costPerRun"
), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have you looked at `apply`? `apply(data, 1, function)` does "cool things" by row. (Changing the "1" to a "2" would do it by column.)

Comment: This doesn't look like a list: do you mean a data frame?

Comment: R says that it is a list when I use the typeof() function. Do I need to convert it to make this feasible?

Comment: Could you please do `dput(Data)` and show what the result is?

Comment: Incidentally, `typeof` applied to a data frame does give *list* (based on the internals of how they're defined). If you do `is.data.frame(Data)` it'll return `TRUE`.

Comment: I added the dput(Data) to the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this using `apply`:

```
apply(Data, 1, function(row) {
    name <- row["name"]
    age <- row["age"]
    #do something cool here
})
```

This is usually used to return a new vector, matrix or list, which depends on what the function returns. For example, let's say you want to apply the function `numberTempSteps / costPerRun` to each row. You would do:

```
apply(Data, 1, function(row) row["numberTempSteps"] / row["costPerRun"])
```

(Note that for this example, you could also just do `Data$numberTempSteps / Data$costPerRun`).

Comment: Thank you! I knew this would be trivial once I got the right eyes to look at it.